# Encoding not correct with Volley JsonObjectRequest API - UTF-8

Tags: android, json, encoding, utf-8, android-volley

I have problem between my API (nodejs) and my android client about encoding.

**Android Volley Request:**

```
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, tmpUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.e("TEST", "" + response.toString());
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            error.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            );
queue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

**Header of my GET request:**

```
content-type → application/json; charset=utf-8
```

**TEST log:**

```
TEST: {"announces":[{"_id":"56360bca8c9356a3289788aa","title":"marchÃ©", ....
```

Normal title should be "*marché*" but it's not working..

Where is the problem ? API or Android client ? I have used this volley lib in different project and everything works properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is necessarily wrong, they just don't match.
Your client is assuming that the encoding of the result is UTF-8, but apparently it is not.

So, you have two choices - either force nodejs to return UTF-8, or figure out what encoding it is returning, and use that on the Android side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When my friend install the apk (on a different phone) its works correctly.. And when it's installed on my phone or the android emulator it's not works..

Comment: Which really doesn't change the answer. You have an encoding mis-match, so you probably need to be explicit on both sides (server and phone), and specify a single encoding in both places (e.g. UTF-8). Letting anything take a default encoding risks having this mismatch.